# Rewriting jQuery into Vanilla JS, querySelector and $(this).html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working function that looks for characters typed into an input field and adds a span element with a highlight class on it.

ATM I am trying to rewrite the the `jQuery` parts of the function into Vanilla JS, and I am running in to some issues. For example I have tried to replace the following `$('.search-suggest__list--categories .search-suggest__highlight')` with a vanilla JS querySelector like this: `document.querySelector('.search-suggest__list--categories .search-suggest__highlight');`, but then when I run the code I get `.each() is not a function` returned.

I also have issues understanding what $(this).html would equal in Vanilla JS.

Here is my function:

```
var search_value = document.getElementsByClassName('js-search-suggest-input')[0].value;

if(search_value.length !== 0){
    $('.search-suggest__list--categories .search-suggest__highlight').each(function(){
        var search_regexp = new RegExp(search_value, "g");
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(search_regexp,"<span class='highlight'>"+search_value+"</span>"));
    });
}
```

Comment: `$(this).html()` => `this.innerHTML` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: "$(this).html()" = this.innerHTML

Comment: To do the equivalent of .each in normal js you will do .forEach((item,index)=>{/*codes goes in here */}); where index can be optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all elements with provided selector.
2. Loop through them using `forEach` - `each` is `jQuery` function, [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) is in `NodeList.prototype`
3. `this.innerHTML` is equivalent of `$(this).html()`. - [innerHTML read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

This should be enough for you to complete the task.